# Mysql sha256 password hashing editing madness!

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, hash

I hash my passwords like so;

```
 hash('sha256', $_POST['password'], date('y/m/d'))
```

Now say a password that is 'aaa' enters my mysql table like so;

```
˜4‡mÏ°\±g¥ÂISë¥ŒJÈ›ßWò/    ¯~èð
```

Now when I go in to edit anything on that row, it will disregard some characters and change it to something along the lines of;

```
˜4‡mÏ°\±g¥ÂISë¥ŒJÈ›
```

I have tried changing all the unicode settings for the mysql connection, the database, tables, and the individual row. I am using PDO, and InnoDB.

Am I doing something daft?!?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The prototype of the [`hash` function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php) is:

```
string hash ( string $algo , string $data [, bool $raw_output = false ] )
```

You're passing `date('y/m/d')` as the third argument, resulting in binary output, as the string is interpreted as `true`.

You probably want hex output.  You should drop that third argument.  You probably wanted to integrate the date into the field somehow, which requires concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

make sure your column has a binary type, or convert your hash to a hex string before inserting it in your db (`bin2hex(hash('sha256', …, …));`)

Answer (score 0):

> Am I doing something daft?!?

Yes. You shouldn't really edit a set of bytes manually in phpMyAdmin. It's not a string, you know.

To ensure the data is ok in DB, ensure your column is of BINARY type and always insert it escaped with mysql_real_escape_string.

Comment: I am using prepared statements anyhow, and I am not changing the password, when I go to edit anything on the row it automatically deletes characters.

Comment: @Version1 You cannot edit binary strings in phpMyAdmin interface